# Função randômica exclusiva e sem repetição - Linguagem C

Tags: c, random

Galera, estou fazendo um programa em linguagem C, e preciso que ele faça alguns sorteios, mas eles não podem ser repetidos, o programa faz o controle de entrada de uma palestra, e terá um sorteio, nesse sorteio não podem ser sorteados os mesmos números, eu estou fazendo sorteio por fileira e cadeira. simulando 30 fileiras e 60 cadeiras em cada fileira, até consegui fazer o sorteio, mas não estou conseguindo tirar as repetições. Segue o código do que fiz, mas não funcionou:

```
void sorteio(int cadeiras[30][60], dados cadastro[3]){

    int a,b,c,d,f[30],p[60],i=0;

    do{
        cadeiras[c=(rand() % 29)][d=(rand() % 59)];
        for (a=0; a>29; a++){
            if(f[a]!=c){
                for (b=0; b>59; b++){
                    if(p[b]!=d){
                        if(cadeiras[c][d]==1){
                            f[i]=c;
                            p[i]=d;
                            i++;
                            printf("\n %d Os sorteado foram: %d fileira %d cadeira", i,c,d);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                for (b=0; b>59; b++){
                    if(p[b]!=d){
                        if(cadeiras[c][d]==1){
                            f[i]=c;
                            p[i]=d;
                            i++;
                            printf("\n %d Os sorteado foram: %d fileira %d cadeira", i,c,d);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //if()
        //if(cadeiras[c][d]==1){
          //  i++;
          //  printf("\n %d Os sorteado foram: %d fileira %d cadeira", i,c,d);
       // }
    }while(i!=15);
}
```

Comment: Para garantir que os números aleatórios sejam gerados sem repetição você precisa armazenar todos os números já gerados e cada novo número só será aceito se ainda não constar da relação dos armazenados.

Comment: Sim, eu pensei nisso, mas não estou conseguindo pensar em uma maneira de guardar de forma eficiente isso, vou editar a pergunta e colocar o código

Comment: Aqui: cadeiras[c=(rand() % 29)][d=(rand() % 59)]; deveria ser: cadeiras[c=(rand() % 30)][d=(rand() % 60)];. Sua condição de parada nos comandos for está errada.

Comment: Para o seu caso creio que você deve gerar fileiras e cadeiras até que todas estejam marcadas como ocupadas.